# Arch won't accept my passwords

Tags: passwords, arch-linux, login

Yesterday I installed arch with Xorg, Lightdm, Lightdm greeter and KDE Plasma 5 as desktop environment, on a external hard drive.

Since the beginning I noticed that it didn't accept my user password (as in, it told me it was incorrect), but I could sign in with my root password, so I just changed my user password, thinking this would fix it. It didn't.

I could still enter with root but never with the user account, regardless of how many time I changed the password. Today I am unable to enter with user or root. I tried to change it using the methods explained here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php..._root_password, but I still couldn't get in.

To make sure of what passwords were stored, I used John the Ripper to see what they were, and this confirmed that I, indeed, was able to change the passwords as explained in the link, but still it wouldtell me that they were incorrect.

I have no idea of what might be happening here. Any idea or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate also posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437927/arch-wont-accept-my-passwords ... I'd rather keep the other one open as it attracted several comments already.

Comment: OP decided (in cross post comments) to reinstall : *Thanks for the help but I decided to reinstall. It was a new install, so nothing but time is lost.* So this post is likely useless.